# Generics in function

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'd like to format rows of a datagridview regarding the "status" property of an object. The function FormatRow can receive any type of object. I came up with this function:

```
Private Sub FormatRow(Of T)()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvHistory.Rows

        Dim obj As T = CType(row.DataBoundItem, T)

        If obj.**Status** = BLL.Configuration.HISTORY_STATUS_ACTIVE Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green
            row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(Control.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

But I can't make it the right way. In the IF statement, the "status" property is not available since my row object is not casted correctly.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer in C#, you do the conversion.

Create an interface IStatus or something like that which contains a Status-property.
Let your entity implement this interface.

Define your function like this:

```
private void FormatRow<T>() where T: IStatus
```

That should do the trick.